# Unable to cast System.Object[] to type System.Security.IPermission ... at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList()

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, linq-to-sql

I am trying to figure out and fix a crash (caused by InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'System.Security.IPermission') which is happening from time to time on our client PCs when the following code is executed:

```
public List<Department> GetDepartmentList()
{
    return DB.Departments.Where(d => d.Gender == SelectedGender && d.IsActive).ToList();
}
```

Why is this exception happening?
How to fix that?

I can not simply put it into try catch block because results from database are necessary.

The code is executed on the main UI thread and no properties/methods are accessed from other threads.

Gender here is an EntityRef property inside Department entity class:

```
[Column(Name = "FK_Gender")]
public int? FK_Gender_Id;

private EntityRef<Gender> gender;
[Association(Name = "FK_Department_Gender", IsForeignKey=true, Storage="gender", ThisKey = "FK_Gender_Id")]
public Gender Gender
{
    get { return gender.Entity; }
    set { gender.Entity = value; }
}
```

GetDepartmentList is called from setter of SelectedGender property which is assigned when user clicks either Male or Female button on a UserControl through bound ICommand SelectGenderCommand:

```
private RelayCommand selectGenderCommand;
public ICommand SelectGenderCommand
{
    get
    {
        return selectGenderCommand ?? (selectGenderCommand = new RelayCommand(param =>
            {
                var genderName = param as string;
                SelectedGender = DB.Genders.Single(g => g.Description == genderName);
                ...

private Gender selectedGender;
public Gender SelectedGender
{
    get { return selectedGender; }
    set
    {
        selectedGender = value;
        DepartmentList = GetDepartmentList();
        NotifyPropertyChanged(() => SelectedGender);
        ...
    }
}
```

DB is a DataContext derived class instance and it is initialized in the constructor of a ViewModel where the GetDepartmentList method is located:

```
public InventoryItemSelectorViewModel(...
{
    DB = new Database();
    DataLoadOptions dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
    dlo.LoadWith<Department>(d => d.Gender);
    DB.LoadOptions = dlo;
    ...
```

The exception stack trace:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'System.Security.IPermission'.
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.PerformSecurityCheck(Object obj, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal method, RuntimeType parent, UInt32 invocationFlags)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.PerformSecurityCheck(Object obj, IRuntimeMethodInfo method, RuntimeType parent, UInt32 invocationFlags)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Data.Linq.CommonDataServices.GetDeferredSourceFactory(MetaDataMember member)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReaderBase`1.GetNestedLinkSource[T](Int32 iGlobalLink, Int32 iLocalFactory, Object instance)
   at Read_Department(ObjectMaterializer`1 )
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at GPFC.ROIPOS.ViewModels.InventoryItemSelectorViewModel.GetDepartmentList() in e:\Projects\POS - Develop\ROIPOS\ROIPOS\ViewModels\InventoryItemSelectorViewModel.cs:line 1173
   at GPFC.ROIPOS.ViewModels.InventoryItemSelectorViewModel.set_SelectedGender(Gender value) in e:\Projects\POS - Develop\ROIPOS\ROIPOS\ViewModels\InventoryItemSelectorViewModel.cs:line 202
   at GPFC.ROIPOS.ViewModels.InventoryItemSelectorViewModel.<get_SelectGenderCommand>b__12(Object param) in e:\Projects\POS - Develop\ROIPOS\ROIPOS\ViewModels\InventoryItemSelectorViewModel.cs:line 978
   at GPFC.ROIPOS.MVVM.RelayCommand.Execute(Object parameter) in e:\Projects\POS - Develop\ROIPOS\ROIPOS\MVVM\RelayCommand.cs:line 168
   at MS.Internal.Commands.CommandHelpers.CriticalExecuteCommandSource(ICommandSource commandSource, Boolean userInitiated)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

One more detail which can be related to the question. Our application is running on several client PCs which all work with one local network database installed on one of the client PCs.

Comment: use try catch.. In catch block, just create a array of type `Department` and then return it to list(`return depArray;`)
`Department[] depArray = new Department[2]; return  depArray; `
Keep this thing in catch block.

Comment: Or somthing like this :
`catch
            {
                return new Department[] { new Department() { A = 1, B = "test", C = "sdfa" } };`
            }

Comment: The results from database are necessary, can't do that.

Comment: In your stacktrace there is a security exception. Maybe this helps: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.methodaccessexception.aspx

Comment: The link leads to MethodAccessException, which is not in the stack trace.

Comment: Does this happen everywhere, or on one machine?  Linq is attempting to use reflection to construct an instance, and this is being blocked by the runtime.  Might be some odd security setting on that user's machine, or maybe the executable/binary isn't trusted (e.g., copied or executed from a network drive), or maybe this is a universal app?  It isn't clear, and I've never seen this before, so I can't say one way or another.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, this is happening occasionally not only on different machines but also in different places in the code when linq-to-sql tries to use System.Reflection. I am getting different kinds of stack traces from different linq-to-sql methods, like SingleOrDefault, Single, when converting results of Where query ToList(), when calling DataContext.Refresh(). I think our clients do not change any standard security settings. The application is installed from downloaded from internet setup file.